# Detect how much browser changed in width on resize and update position of element

Tags: javascript, html, css

There is one div element positioned absolutely in a relative container. It is initially positioned under one of four buttons. Based on which button is clicked, I calculate with JS the x coordinate of the button and move the div element underneath that button. Here's my markup and JS:

```
<div id='container-of-four-buttons' style="width: 100%; position: relative;">
 <button>Foo</button>
 <button>Buzz</button>
 <button>Foo</button>
 <button>Buzz</button>
</div>

<div id='followAlong-container' style="width: 100%; position: relative;">
<div class='followAlong-div' style="position:absolute; width: 15px; height: 13px;">Some stylized arrow</div>
</div>

var initialDiv = /* selected the second button to be initial */
var followAlongDiv = document.querySelector('followAlong-div');
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

followAlongDiv.style.left = initialDiv + 89 + 'px';


buttons.forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let xCoord = 0;
    xCoord += (div.offsetLeft - div.scrollLeft + div.clientLeft);
    followAlongDiv.style.left = xPos + 17 + 'px';
  });
});
```

However, if I resize the browser, the four button elements shrink towards eachother, but the followAlongDiv stays at the same spot because it is positioned absolutely in its relative container.

How do I calculate the amount of width the browser has resized and update the position of the followAlongDiv?

I will use window.addEventListener('resize', updatePosition), but I just don't know how to approach the formulation of the updatePosition function.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but if you want to reposition your div after resize, put the same code of the click function handler in the resize function handler, and in the click handler hold a reference to the clicked button so you can use it in the resize function

Comment: @ShacharW, tnx. How do I pass in the reference to the clicked button from the click function to the resize function?

Comment: outside of your handlers add a variable - var button;
in the click handler assign the button - button = this;
in the resize handler you can use the button variable.

Answer (score 0):

First, '*followAlong-div*' is a class (needs '.' before the className ):

> var followAlongDiv = document.querySelector('.followAlong-div');

Second, I do not understand why you have this line:

> xCoord += (div.offsetLeft - div.scrollLeft + div.clientLeft);

For resizing just needs:

```
window.onresize = ()=>{
          var xCoord = 0;
          xCoord += (selectedButton.offsetLeft);
          followAlongDiv.style.left = xCoord + 'px';

}
```

Based on your code, I think this is what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/vua4eLhc/

Hope it helps!